# Symfony2 : installation of composer.phar

Tags: symfony, components

I would like to install the composer.phar in my symfony application I download the call since https://github.com/composer/composer.

but when I run the command:

```
 php composer.phar install
```

i have this in my consol :

```
 Problem 1

-Installation request for symfony/icu v1.2.1 -> satisfiable by symfony/icu[v1.2.1]

-symfony/icu v1.2.1 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked library icu has the extension providing it.

Problem 2

-symfony/symfony v2.5.0 requires symfony/icu ~1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/icu[v1.2.1].

-symfony/symfony v2.5.0 requires symfony/icu ~1.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/icu[v1.2.1].

-symfony/icu v1.2.1 requires lib-icu >=4.4 -> the requested linked  library icu has the wrong version installed or is missing from your system, make sure have the extension providing it.

- Installation request for symfony/symfony v2.5.0 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v2.5.0].
```

any help please !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install/update [a php intl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php).

Comment: i have this in my composer.json:                                         "php" : ">=5.3.3",
  "symfony/symfony" : "2.5.*",
  "doctrine/orm" : "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
  "doctrine/doctrine-bundle" : "~1.2",
  "twig/extensions" : "~1.0",
  "symfony/assetic-bundle" : "~2.3",
  "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle" : "~2.3",
  "symfony/monolog-bundle" : "~2.4",
  "sensio/distribution-bundle" : "~3.0",
  "sensio/framework-extra-bundle" : "~3.0",
  "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler" : "~2.0",
  "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle" : "~2.0@dev"

Comment: what kind of system do you use: windows or linux?

Comment: please, check out [this thread](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33688/installing-git-sudo-apt-get-command-not-found), maybe it can help you

Comment: if you want to use symfony 2.5 you must install/update php-intl extension.

Comment: i use now symfony 2.5 and i would use FosuserBundle but i have problem in composer.phar, is there another way to install this Bundle without using composer?

Comment: you can upload bundle from github repository and put it to vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle, than you must follow [installation guide](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#installation) from step 2

Comment: skip Step 1 in this guide, if it does not work you must install php-intl extension